# Google Distroless Image for JDK 13

Tags: dockerfile, jib, azul-zulu

Has google published distroless image for JDK 13? If not, what's the best alternative to use for JDK 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the openjdk images.  Distroless is oriented towards long-term support images (LTS).  Java 13 is not an LTS image and I'm not aware of any organizations that are supporting Java 13 beyond the end of this month (March 2020).